# FFMPEG wrapping live h264 to mp4 container delay

Tags: ffmpeg

Sorry if this has been asked but I couldn't find the answer.

I'm trying to wrap a live raw h264 stream to a fragmented MP4 container. This is working as expected, with one issue, I have a 5-10 seconds delay between the input and output. Basically the output start after 5-10 seconds of the first input received.

This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f h264 -i tcp://127.0.0.1:1234 -c:v copy -an -f mp4 -movflags separate_moof+empty_moov+default_base_moof -tune zerolatency -tcp_nodelay true -frag_duration 33000 -max_muxing_queue_size 1 tcp://127.0.0.1:1235
```

I have played with fflags, with analyzeduration and with everything I could find in the documentation but no joy.

The input stream is receiving NALU units and I can see that it receives a significant amount of units before it actually starts outputting. Once it starts it works perfect, but the output video is always 5-10 seconds behind the input one.

After a bunch of NALU units received I see ffmpeg outputting the following:

```
2021-08-02 23:46:22.071 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: Input #0, h264, from 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8105':
2021-08-02 23:46:22.071 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit:   Duration: 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.071 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: N/A
2021-08-02 23:46:22.071 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: , bitrate: 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.071 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: N/A
2021-08-02 23:46:22.071 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit:   Stream #0:0
2021-08-02 23:46:22.071 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: : Video: h264, yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 1280x720
2021-08-02 23:46:22.071 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: , 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.072 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: 30 fps, 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.072 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: 30 tbr, 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.072 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: 1200k tbn, 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.072 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: 60 tbc
2021-08-02 23:46:22.079 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: Output #0, mp4, to 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8104':
2021-08-02 23:46:22.079 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit:   Metadata:
2021-08-02 23:46:22.079 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit:     encoder         : 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.079 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: Lavf58.67.100
2021-08-02 23:46:22.079 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit:   Stream #0:0
2021-08-02 23:46:22.079 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 1280x720, q=2-31
2021-08-02 23:46:22.080 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: , 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.080 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: 30 fps, 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.080 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: 30 tbr, 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.080 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: 15360 tbn, 
2021-08-02 23:46:22.080 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: 30 tbc
2021-08-02 23:46:22.080 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: Stream mapping:
2021-08-02 23:46:22.080 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
2021-08-02 23:46:22.080 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit:  (copy)
2021-08-02 23:46:22.080 24626-11173/app.example.com I/ffmpeg-kit: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

That is an Android wrapper, but same thing happen if I run the command on my laptop from the command line.

What am I'm missing, I need this to be real-time / instant muxing...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue shortly after posting the question.....

using the `-probesize 512` fixed the issue.

Why 512?

My SDP+SSP is about 270 bytes, so to be on the safe side I've used slightly higher value. Reducing the probesize made it all work nice.

It is also important to have the option BEFORE the input entry so ffmpeg knows that is should be applied to that.